# Which commercial aircraft are capable of computer-only landings, without human assistance?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing, commercial-aviation, autopilot

Currently what models of commercial aircraft are capable of landing and safely stopping the aircraft, without any human assistance, other than inputting instructions to the onboard computers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

None. While a number of aircraft are certified for autoland with automatic rollout until safe taxi speed, and some can have the autopilot control rollout until the aircraft completely stops, no commercial aircraft has autopilot control of various critical parts for landing such as the flaps and the landing gear.

Comment: Isn't that typically part of approach and not landing?