# Is the autopilot system capable of taking off and landing a plane?

Tags: landing, takeoff, autopilot

I am aware of the fact that the autopilot is engaged after takeoff and disengaged before final approach but I was just wondering whether or not the autopilot is capable of landing or taking off a plane.

Comment: For landing, see [Which commercial aircraft are capable of computer-only landings, without human assistance?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14525/923)

Comment: depends, which "autopilot system" of the several existing are we speaking of?

Comment: Not familiar with ANY autopilot that is ever used for takeoff with a manned aircraft. Some autopilots are capable of auto-land, although the requirements for the compatible systems on the ground are quite strict.

Comment: @RalphJ for now :P

Comment: No and there is no point in auto takeoff because pilots are trained to do this themselves and if technology fails on an aircraft the pilot wouldn't know what to do and if there was a such thing as autotakeoff and landing pilots would count on technology to do the work for them. I know this is an old question but this is what I do when I am bored on this website